# Fechar arquivo (está sendo usado por outro processo)

Tags: c#

O código que estou tentando usar é o seguinte (modifiquei apenas o caminho e o conteúdo), antes dessas linhas eu faço uma verificação se o arquivo não existe, ou seja ele só executa isso se o arquivo não existir (para não sobrescrever o mesmo)

```
File.Create("caminho-arq"); // cria arquivo
File.OpenWrite("caminho-arq"); // abre arquivo para edição
File.WriteAllText("caminho-arq", "conteudo\r\nvai\r\naqui"); // escreve no arquivo
// \r\n começa uma nova linha no arquivo
```

A linha do `File.OpenWrite` foi minha última tentativa, mesmo sem ela não funciona, dá erro dizendo "O arquivo 'caminho-arq' não pode ser alterado, pois já está sendo usado em outro processo." Ontem eu enfrentei o mesmo problema, mas não era criando o arquivo, pois ele já estava criado, era pra ler, depois salvar. Então usei o `StreamRead`, li e peguei informações e fechei o arquivo, depois usei o `File.WriteAllText` para adicionar novas informações.. Mas agra não sei como fazer, não existe um `File.Close()` pra fechar o arquivo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essa linha `File.Create("caminho-arq");` cria o arquivo e te retorna um [`FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx) pra que você possa usar, se você não for usar você tem que fechar ela antes de abrir uma nova.

```
File.Create("caminho-arq").Close();
```

Você precisa decidir qual método vai usar, porque suas 2 primeiras linhas abrem um `FileStream` isso sempre vai gerar conflito pra acessar o arquivo.

- *public static* **FileStream** [OpenWrite()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite(v=vs.110).aspx)
- *public static* **FileStream** [Create()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx)

#### A melhor maneira pra escrita do arquivo

```
using(StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("caminho-arq"))
{                                
    sw.WriteLine("teste");                     
    sw.WriteLine("123");         
}
```

O método [`.AppendText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx) retorna um `StreamWriter` e **cria** o arquivo caso ele não existir, então você não precisa se preocupar pra ver se ele já existe ou não. E como está utilizando o `using` na `Stream` ele automaticamente da um `.Close()` quando sai do `}`.

Comment: Valeu, eu nunca iria pensar que só faltava um .Close() no final.. Sim, eu usei o dois só como última tentativa, sabia que não iria funcionar.. apaguei a linha do OpenWrite e acrescentei o .Close() na Create e funcionou perfeitamente. Só estou esperando o tempo aqui para escolher como resposta certa :)

Comment: @LeonardoVIlarinho Melhorei a resposta :)

Comment: Concordo `using(StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("caminho-arq"))` é o melhor caminho +1