# Upload - o processo não pode acessar o arquivo porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou tentando montar um gerenciador de arquivos, mas estou encontrando um problema na hora de atualizar o arquivo. Primeiro faço o `upload` do arquivo, e depois disso, caso o usuário deseje atualizar, tenho a opção de atualização, onde altera o arquivo, ou seja, faz o upload e sobrepõe o já existe. Nisso, está dando o seguinte erro: `o processo não pode acessar o arquivo porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo`. Segue o código que estou utilizando para `cadastro` e `edição`.

**CADASTRO**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Cadastrar(Arquivo arquivo, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
    {
        using (var ts = _db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var nome = CriptografiaUtil.Outros(DateTime.Now.ToString()) + Path.GetExtension(upload.FileName);
                    var urlUpload = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(DiretorioUpload.Arquivo()), nome);
                    upload.SaveAs(urlUpload);
                    arquivo.Url = DiretorioUpload.Arquivo() + nome;
                    ArquivoDAO.Cadastrar(arquivo, ref _db);
                    ts.Commit();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                return View(arquivo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ts.Rollback();
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIÇÃO**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Atualizar(Arquivo arquivo, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
    using (var ts = _db.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (upload != null)
                {
                    var arquivoCadastrado = ArquivoDAO.Buscar(arquivo.Id, ref _db);
                    var nomeArquivoCad = Path.GetFileName(arquivo.Url);
                    if (nomeArquivoCad != null)
                    {
                        var urlUpload = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(DiretorioUpload.Arquivo()), nomeArquivoCad);
                        upload.SaveAs(urlUpload);
                    }
                }
                ArquivoDAO.Editar(arquivo, ref _db);
                ts.Commit();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(arquivo);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ts.Rollback();
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Como podem ver, na edição eu apenas sobreponho o arquivo já cadastrado, para que ao trocar o arquivo o antigo fique no servidor sem necessidade.

Comment: O arquivo está aberto quando você tenta realizar esse processo?

Comment: Não, nada disso @DiegoAugusto

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71643/fechar-arquivo-est%C3%A1-sendo-usado-por-outro-processo

Comment: Nesse exemplo ai ele cria um arquivo, mas não realiza o upload @DiegoAugusto